# PHP fwrite() randomly adds blank lines

Tags: php, file, fwrite

I have a 9x9 sudoku matrix filled with numbers that I'm trying to display on the screen and save in a file. The first part works easily but when I try to save the matrix in a file, I get random blank lines in it and I can't figure out why or how. Here's the code that I have:

```
    $file = fopen($fileName, "w");
    for ($row = 0; $row < 9; $row++)
    {
        for ($col = 0; $col < 9; $col++)
        {
            fwrite($file, $this->grid[$row][$col] . " ");
        }   
        fwrite($file, PHP_EOL);
    }

    fclose($file);
```

This is supposed to give me 9 rows with 9 columns and spaces between them, however, I get something different each time based on the numbers in the grid. Here's an example:

```
1 5 9 7 2 3 4 6 8 
2 3 6 4 8 5 9 7 1

8 4 7 6 9 1 2 3 5 
3 6 8 9 4 7 1 5 2 
9 1 2 8 5 6 3 4 7 
4 7 5 1 3 2 6 8 9

5 8 3 2 6 9 7 1 4 
7 2 4 3 1 8 5 9 6

6 9 1 5 7 4 8 2 3
```

The blank lines with those numbers are always on the same place. Here's another one with different numbers in it:

```
5 1 6 9 7 3 2 8 4

2 7 3 4 8 5 9 6 1

8 4 9 1 2 6 7 5 3

9 5 7 6 3 1 4 2 8

3 8 1 2 4 7 6 9 5

6 2 4 8 5 9 1 3 7

7 3 2 5 6 4 8 1 9 
1 6 5 7 9 8 3 4 2

4 9 8 3 1 2 5 7 6
```

And every now and then I might get one that actually looks ok like this one:

```
6 4 3 7 8 9 2 5 1 
9 1 8 2 3 5 4 6 7 
5 7 2 6 1 4 8 3 9 
1 3 4 8 9 6 5 7 2 
7 9 5 3 4 2 1 8 6 
8 2 6 1 5 7 9 4 3 
2 8 7 4 6 1 3 9 5 
3 5 1 9 7 8 6 2 4 
4 6 9 5 2 3 7 1 8
```

The code is the same, the only thing that changes are the numbers in the grid. If I replace the fwrite's with echos it all works fine in the browser and displays everything correctly but as soon as I send it to a file it gets messy.
Any suggestions as I'm totally clueless what's happening?

EDIT:
I found out that the values in the grid were stored as strings so as soon as I changed a line to this:

```
fwrite($file, intval($this->grid[$row][$col]) . " ");
```

The output in the file started to look alright. However, I'm still uncertain why the strings would sometimes cause a problem.

Comment: Do your debugging first. It's nice showing those outputs, but it would be better to show exactly what kinds of whitespace you get in there. Are those blank lines extra `\n`s? `\r\n`s? Something else?

Comment: @Jon You can see in the code he is using `PHP_EOL`

Comment: How can I check that? I'm using PHP_EOL on purpose so I don't have to deal with \n or \r\n's

Comment: @Akshay2598: Based on the code the observed effect is impossible because all lines should display the same. So debugging starts with examining the actual output. At least that's how I would do it.

Comment: @mmvsbg Maybe sometimes it's `\n` and other times it's `\r\n`. Try using those instead of `PHP_EOL` see if that makes a difference.

Comment: My guess is the extra newlines are in some of the `$grid` elements. Look at the code that fills the array.

Comment: Well, the numbers were actually stored in the grid as strings, so as soon as I used an intval() around each call to the grid, it all started to look fine in the output file but the reason why it would give a problem with the strings is still a mistery...

Comment: It seems wither (a) some `$row`'s do no exist, or (b) some `$col`'s at the end of a row have newlines attached to their value. An `intval()` (or `trim()`) would remove that extra whitespace from the end.

Comment: @mmvsbg Are you reading the numbers in from a file? If you use `file()`, it leaves the newlines in the results unless you use `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES`.

Comment: Thank you Barmar, I was reading the input from a file indeed, so that solves that mystery. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Thats simple - some of original values in grids have content not "123", but "123\n" in it or "\n123". By looking at your examples - that's always last element of grid row.

Instead of intval() you can also use str_replace to strip \n and \r values for example like this str_replace(array("\n","\r"),"",$this->grid[$x][$y])